# Dictionary Sorting In Incorrect Order

Tags: python, dictionary

See My code below:

```
import operator
mydict = {'carl': 4,
          'alan': 2,
          'bob': 1,
          'danny': 3}

for i in sorted(mydict,key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True):
    print ("%s: %d" % (i,mydict[i]))
```

I got output:

```
bob: 1
alan: 2
carl: 4
danny: 3
```

I am expecting:

```
bob: 1
alan: 2
danny: 3
carl: 4
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: if you're trying to sort by values, you'll need to pass `mydict.items()`, and modify your loop to take two loop variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're sorting the people's names by the second letter of their name, not sorting key-value pairs by value. `'carl'` and `'danny'` both have second letter `'a'`.

If you want a dict's key-value pairs, use its `items()`:

```
for k, v in sorted(mydict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pass mydict.items(). This works:

```
import operator
mydict = {'carl': 4,
          'alan': 2,
          'bob': 1,
          'danny': 3}

# for i in sorted(mydict,key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True):
#     print ("%s: %d" % (i,mydict[i]))

sorted_x = sorted(mydict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print(sorted_x)
```